# Error al subir proyecto de laravel a github

Tags: laravel, git, fetch, git-push

Quería subir mi proyecto de Laravel a Github. Así que dentro de la carpeta del mismo hice `git init, git add ., git commit -m ".."` y el `git remote add origin 'url de mi repositorio'`.. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero al hacer `git push -u origin` todo se va al diablo, me sale el error y no hay manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He configurado y probado todas las combinaciones posibles que me dice el error y no doy con la tecla.

Comment: te esta diciendo que el repositorio ya contiene un codigo que en tu rama no tienes.  Por lo tanto, primero debes integrar esos cambios en tu local, y luego subirlos. Por un casual hay otro programador trabajando en master y te ha subido cosas? o ya tenias creado el repositorio y no te has bajado el codigo que tenias antes?

Comment: No, y por mucho que intente bajarmelo con git pull no se puede porque no hay nada, el repositorio está recién creado y no había llegado a subir nada a él porque no me deja, simplemente siempre me sale el mismo error.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo del mensaje, el repositorio remoto ya tenía contenido a la hora de asociarlo con tu local. Por defecto con `git init` te va a crear un repo con la rama `master`, que coincide con la rama por defecto cuando se crea un repo de **github**.

La consola te está diciendo que te traigas el contenido de lo que había en `master` del repo remoto. Probaste con `git fetch` en tus intentos? Un `git pull` también debería de funcionar si es lo que creo.

Comment: Sí, probé ambos y no se solucionaba, aunque me cambió una cosa y es que en vez de aparecerme a la derecha de master ese paréntesis con "fetch first" ponía "not-forward" o algo parecido.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema y el error que estaba cometiendo era que tenia creada la carpeta .git fuera del la carpeta de donde tenia mi proyecto clonado.

las elimine y realice el proceso nuevamente.